# Dart callback isn't defined for the type _SignaturePadState

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use callback for dart to retrieve value from a child in dart if the user already input their signature. This is what i have but the callback function is highlighted in red when I try to use it stating:

```
The method 'callback' isn't defined for the type '_SignaturePadState'.
```

Callback returns a boolean value based on the api response. This is what I have.

**PARENT**

```
bool hasSigned = false;

bool _updateValueSigned(bool value) {
  setState(() {
    hasSigned = value;
  });
  return value;
}
```

**CHILD**

```
class SignaturePad extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(bool) callback;

  SignaturePad({required this.callback});

  @override
  _SignaturePadState createState() => _SignaturePadState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //.... other codes
body: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
//... lines of code

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {

    callback(true); // this line throws the error mentioned above.
  },
  child: Text('Save'.toUpperCase()),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  ),
),
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call widget variable from state class, It will be

```
// widget.variableName
widget.callback(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever You want to use widget variable declare from state class, you need to
write like this //widget.variable,   In ur case it will be

```
widget.callback(true);
```